# C# chrome tab get index

Tags: c#, google-chrome

We currently know Chrome inside information via SetWinEventHook + AccessibleObjectFromEvent.
But I do not know the index of tabs that are active in Chrome
Is there a way to solve this problem?
If you have difficulty performing tasks
Ctrl + left mouse click on a link in Chrome
A new background tab is created.(no focus)
I want to do this in C #.
Help.

Comment: PS. I Konw Chome Handle

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Yang Se Hoon. Can you give us more background information on what you're trying to do, so that others can have all the relevant information to assist you.